# At insert_id() , get last insert id in codeigniter extra 1 is coming with id

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3, last-insert-id

When using `insert_id()` to receiving the last Auto increment insert ID , then extra `1` is coming with every id , when doing `echo print($insert_id)` at **MODEL** in CodeIgniter.

**For Example:** My last Auto Increment id at database column is **50** when doing `echo ($insert_id);` it showing me **501** as my last increment id. Very strange. I could not able to find out the problem why extra 1 is coming. 
Any suggestion, please help me out.

**My Another question** is after receiving the Last Insert Id, how to receive the **ID** to *Controller file* at Codeigniter from *Modal File*.

**Modal**

```html
public function create($data = [])
{  
   $this->db->insert($this->table,$data);
   $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
   echo print_r($insert_id);exit;
    
   //return $insert_id ;
}
```

Comment: Actually `print_r($insert_id)`  return `true` which written as 1 in web page by `echo`.

Comment: you are using `echo` and `print_r()` at same time

Comment: The extra "1" comes from echoing the response of print_r()

Comment: If you want to print out the response of print_r using echo, you have to set the second parameter to true

Comment: Thank you to all I got the point .   Any one can please suggest me my 2nd Query **after receiving the Last Insert Id , how to received the ID to Controller file at Codeigniter from Modal File** ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

**Note** : *Use  only `echo` to print the insert id in your model; and to get the id in controller just return `$insert_id`*

*Your model should be like this :*

```
public function create($data = [])
{   
   if (! empty($data))
   { 
     $this->db->insert($this->table,$data);
     $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
     return $insert_id;
   }
}
```

*In your controller :*

**Note** : *make sure you have loaded your model either in autoload or in controller*

```
public function method_name()
{
  $data = ['your insert data in array'];
  $id = $this->model_name->create($data);
  echo $id;//you will get the id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggest me . But sir here you suggest me - **make sure you have loaded your model either in autoload or in controller** - which I donot understand. Could you please elaborate me ?

Comment: you need to add model file which you have in models folder using this `$this->load->model('model_name');`   for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: Sir, is it mandatory to receiving the LAST ID , used **$data = ['your insert data in array'];** on my controller function method ??

Comment: no not at all its just depends upon , if you want to use this id for further use just return otherwise not necessary

Comment: Actually sir, in my  task , I have **2 Table** in  my database.After insert all data in 1st table then send some 3type of data send to 2nd table on the same Operation . So I made the controller function as serial operation. In 2nd table I need to send also the **LAST INSERT ID of 1st TABLE**  . Here I can able to send other 2 data except the **last insert Id** . Could you please suggest me , if I am share the controller function to you Sir ?

Comment: so if you want to send last insert id to other table just return it from model

Comment: Sir , I am doing the same , but getting some error. !

Comment: Sir I share my controller code below . Could you please help me .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172935/discussion-between-biswajit17-and-pradeep).